# Javascript CSV file download issue in FireFox, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have some code which downloads some data into a csv file which works great on chrome but doesn't do anything on firefox (no errors)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        var data = [
           ['idea', 'a very good one'],
           ['beer', 'not when driving'],
           ['guitar', 'yes please']
        ];


        function download_csv() {
            var csv = 'Name,Title\n';
            data.forEach(function(row) {
                    csv += row.join(',');
                    csv += "\n";
            });

            console.log(csv);
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'test.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();
        }

    </script>

    <button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is it not working in firefox?

Comment: I have updated the working code below and give a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You are creating an element and invoking the `click` event of the
>   element without adding the same to the `DOM`. That's
>   why it's not working in `FireFox`.

I created a hidden div `<div id="container" style="display:none;"></div>` and appended the `hiddenElement` you created to this `div` then trigger the `click` event which is now causing `FireFox` to download the csv.

That's it :-)

I tested in `FireFox` and `Chrome` and both are looking good.

Modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        var data = [
           ['idea', 'a very good one'],
           ['beer', 'not when driving'],
           ['guitar', 'yes please']
        ];


        function download_csv() {
            var csv = 'Name,Title\n';
            data.forEach(function(row) {
                    csv += row.join(',');
                    csv += "\n";
            });

            console.log(csv);
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'test.csv';
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(hiddenElement);
            hiddenElement.click();
        }

    </script>

    <button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>
    <div id="container" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not getting a popup blocker. Sometime if operation is performed late after user action then popup blocker of browser comes into action.

Answer (score 0):

I had put the log (console.log(a)) after `document.createElement('a')` both firefox and Chrome. i observe that in chrome automatically adding closing tag but not in Firefox, So you can create anchor tag with hidden property and refer that in your JS. It Should work.
Exmaple:

```
<div id="report_wraper"> 
 <table> some rows and col ....</table> 
</div>
<button id="d">Export csv</button>
<a style="display:none" id="dtag"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
   var table_div = document.getElementById('report_wrapper');
   var table_html = encodeURI(table_div.outerHTML);  // your table div
   var a = document.getElementById("dtag");
   a.href = data_type + ", " + table_html; 
   a.download = "report"+ new Date()+ ".xls";
   a.click();
</script>
```